# Overflow while working with SD library

Tags: sd-card, esp32

i am currently working on a Project with an SD card. I want to open a .csv-file on my sd card (later it should be the last file) and then read the ID that is at the start of the .csv-file.

Yesterday it worked like a charm but now i get `-1` as output for every read() or peek() i use. I cant seem to work out the problem. It could probably be anything in my code but i hope the error lies in this function

Any help is very appreciated.

This is my function:

```
unsigned int EKG_recording::get_record_from_SD(File dir)
{
  Serial.println("Its in the function\n");
  //dir.rewindDirectory();
  File entry = dir.openNextFile();

  Serial.println(entry.name());

  if (entry)
  {
    first_digit = entry.read(); //ASCII CODE 
    Serial.println("one digit:");
    Serial.println(first_digit);

    Serial.println("peek:");
    Serial.println(entry.peek());

    if (entry.peek() == seperator) { // Check if next Byte ";" 
      Serial.println("one digit");
      Serial.println((first_digit - '0'));
      return (first_digit - '0');
    }

    second_digit = entry.read();
    Serial.println("2 digit:");
    Serial.println(second_digit);

    Serial.println("peek:");
    Serial.println(entry.peek());

    if (entry.peek() == seperator) { // Check if next Byte ";"
      all_digits = (first_digit - '0') * 10 + (second_digit - '0') ;
      Serial.println("two digits");
      Serial.println(all_digits);
      return (all_digits);
    }

    third_digit = entry.read();
    Serial.println("3 digit:");
    Serial.println(third_digit);

    Serial.println("peek:");
    Serial.println(entry.peek());

    if (entry.peek() == seperator) { // Check if next Byte ";"
      all_digits = (first_digit - '0') * 100 + (second_digit - '0') * 10 + (third_digit - '0');
      Serial.println("Three digits");
      Serial.println(all_digits);
      return (all_digits);
    }
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("No File found");
  }

  entry.close();

}
```

I think i get some kind of overflow because all Serial.prints return -1

```
13:20:09.630 -> Its in the function
13:20:09.630 -> 
13:20:09.630 -> /System Volume Information
13:20:09.630 -> one digit:
13:20:09.630 -> -1
13:20:09.630 -> peek:
13:20:09.630 -> -1
13:20:09.630 -> 2 digit:
13:20:09.630 -> -1
13:20:09.630 -> peek:
13:20:09.630 -> -1
13:20:09.630 -> 3 digit:
13:20:09.630 -> -1
13:20:09.630 -> peek:
13:20:09.630 -> -1
13:20:09.630 ->
```

This are my variables for the function

```
//Funktion get_record_id
     int first_digit = 0;
     int second_digit = 0;
     int third_digit = 0;
     int all_digits = 0;
    unsigned int seperator = 59;
```

I call the function like this. I dont create folders or anything on the SD-Card, it just contains .csv-files

```
File root = SD.open("/");
  EKG_recording_1.get_last_record_from_SD(root);
```

Here is the CardInfo Example for ESP32

```
17:14:22.777 -> SD Card Type: SDHC
17:14:22.777 -> SD Card Size: 7624MB
17:14:22.777 -> Listing directory: /
17:14:22.777 ->   DIR : /System Volume Information
17:14:22.777 ->   FILE: /1.CSV  SIZE: 9060
17:14:22.811 ->   FILE: /2.CSV  SIZE: 9060
17:14:22.811 ->   FILE: /3.CSV  SIZE: 9056
17:14:22.811 ->   FILE: /4.CSV  SIZE: 9056
17:14:22.811 -> Creating Dir: /mydir
17:14:22.913 -> Dir created
17:14:22.913 -> Listing directory: /
17:14:22.913 ->   DIR : /System Volume Information
17:14:22.913 ->   DIR : /mydir
17:14:22.913 ->   FILE: /1.CSV  SIZE: 9060
17:14:22.913 ->   FILE: /2.CSV  SIZE: 9060
17:14:22.946 ->   FILE: /3.CSV  SIZE: 9056
17:14:22.946 ->   FILE: /4.CSV  SIZE: 9056
17:14:22.946 -> Removing Dir: /mydir
17:14:22.980 -> Dir removed
17:14:22.980 -> Listing directory: /
17:14:22.980 ->   DIR : /System Volume Information
17:14:22.980 -> Listing directory: /System Volume Information
17:14:22.980 ->   FILE: /System Volume Information/WPSettings.dat  SIZE: 12
17:14:22.980 ->   FILE: /System Volume Information/IndexerVolumeGuid  SIZE: 76
17:14:23.013 ->   FILE: /1.CSV  SIZE: 9060
17:14:23.013 ->   FILE: /2.CSV  SIZE: 9060
17:14:23.046 ->   FILE: /3.CSV  SIZE: 9056
17:14:23.046 ->   FILE: /4.CSV  SIZE: 9056
17:14:23.046 -> Writing file: /hello.txt
17:14:23.046 -> File written
17:14:23.080 -> Appending to file: /hello.txt
17:14:23.113 -> Message appended
17:14:23.113 -> Reading file: /hello.txt
17:14:23.113 -> Read from file: Hello World!
17:14:23.113 -> Deleting file: /foo.txt
17:14:23.113 -> Delete failed
17:14:23.113 -> Renaming file /hello.txt to /foo.txt
17:14:23.146 -> File renamed
17:14:23.146 -> Reading file: /foo.txt
17:14:23.146 -> Read from file: Hello World!
17:14:23.146 -> Failed to open file for reading
17:14:32.208 -> 1048576 bytes written for 9036 ms
17:14:32.208 -> Total space: 7604MB
17:14:32.208 -> Used space: 1MB
```

Comment: `/System Volume Information` -- Is that *really* the file you want to open...?

Comment: I dont even know what this is. I want to open the main folder so "/". Do you know what /System Volume Information is or how i can open the root folder? I never had that name thats why i put it in there

Comment: Ok it seems like there is some invisible folder on my sd card that i cant delete. I already formated the sd card. It still shows up. I think i will just test if the dir.openNextFile() chatches a folder or a file

Comment: That file is created by Windows for storing extended attribute information.

Comment: Well how can i work around this problem? Always delete System Volume Information at the beginning or what should i do?
`while(entry.isDirectory()){
    entry = dir.openNextFile();
  }`
Ok i just used this to test if i get a folder from dir.openNextFile(), now i get correct return values again

Comment: SD library doesn't use long file names. run the CardInfo example

Comment: I edited it to the Main post

Comment: try `unsigned int EKG_recording::get_record_from_SD(File& dir)`